# Using Waitress yields "This page isn’t working" for django project however works fine with python manage.py runserver

Tags: python, django, waitress

I am working on uploading my django project to heroku for beta testing, however am encountering an issue using waitress.

```
$ waitress-serve --listen=*:8000 mysite.wsgi:application
```

I used this line of code on the gitbash to test if waitress was working - got this as a result:

```
INFO:waitress:Serving on http://[::]:8000
INFO:waitress:Serving on http://0.0.0.0:8000
```

I clicked on both of the links, but both of them result in "The Page isn't working" and an "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"

However, when I run python manage.py runserver, it works totally fine, and my django project gets pulled up and functions properly.

I was wondering if anyone could provide any advice on how to fix this?